# Subdomain Apache2.4 Not Working Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I have a server running Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 16.04. I have configured my sites-available/dnd.devosmium.xyz.conf like so:
https://pastebin.com/s09aB8Pg

I have run the `a2enmod dnd.devosmium.xyz.conf` command, and reloaded/restarted apache2. Whenever I go to my site I get my sites homepage.

Comment: You are missing a few things....you need to set the `ServerName` to `dnd.devosmium.xyz` and also, update your hosts file `etc\hosts` to match the subdomain

Comment: My servername is set to dnd.devosmium.xyz (line 9). What do you mean by edit my `etc/hosts` file?

Comment: For example, let's say that you have the following `ServerName ServerName www.dnd.devosmium.xyz` and `ServerAlias ServerName dnd.devosmium.xyz` in your `vhost` file....you need to edit your host file like `127.0.0.1 www.dnd.devosmium.xyz dnd.devosmium.xyz`...adding that line and reloading you apache server should do the trick.

Comment: I don't have a vhost file, and I added that line to my hosts file and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, you need to edit the default apache2.conf to allow requests to /var/www/*